# what charset is the good one

Tags: browser, character-encoding

here is ONE LINE of a csv file i got :

"444","444","SIEGE SOCIAL","2568","avenue Montbray",,"QuÈbec","QC","G1V1E8","4186520123"

the problem, when i display that : "QuÈbec" is supposed to be Québec

When i DOES NOT define ANY charset ... Québec is just fine
when i set charset to : charset=UTF-8 the result is : Qu�bec

so the question, how to define charset the right way to get the accent correct !

thanks

Comment: More information is needed. How do you display the data? Your program must be using *some* character encoding to interpret the data, which? And can you provide other examples of problematic characters in the data?

Comment: I am on a mac, do the .txt file is a textedit file (encoding ???) and i display it in Firefox with PHP code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character encoding (“charset”) is probably ISO-8859-1, windows-1252, or some similar encoding, and you are viewing the data with a program that interprets it according to the Mac Roman encoding. In ISO-8859-1, “é” is 0xE9. Interpreted as Mac Roman, byte 0xE9 means “È”.

With the given data, it is impossible to distinguish between various 8-bit encodings that represent “é” as 0xE9 (such as ISO-8859-1 and ISO-8859-2).

Comment: what you need to help ? the txt file ?

Comment: You could try declaring the encoding as windows-1252. It’s probably the correct guess. But for an analysis, we need some other pieces of text, containing other problem characters, with content from which one can infer what is being meant.